# Interpreting results of cubic regression

Tags: regression, polynomial

I have a simple question. I'm doing a regression with countries (346 countries). I have a variable that measures level of previous conflict. I rescaled this variable in a variable that goes **from 0.0 (minimum) to 1.0 (maximum)** (mean 0.16 and SD = 0.23). I found that I need a quadratic and a cubic term of this variable.
My dependent variable is attitudes towards abortion at the national level and it goes from 0 to 9.
Now I found that my intercept is 1.74, my main term (conflict) is -7.00, my quadratic term is 17.32 and my cubic term is -10.15.
How do I interpret this?

These are raw polynomials.

Comment: Has conflict been analysed as a "raw" or an orthogonal polynomial?

Comment: It is a raw one.

Comment: Nope, it isn't. Im not using orthogonal polynomials. This output comes from Mplus and not R.

Comment: The statistical content remains the same whatever software you're using. If you need software help, please consult our help center for a list of support links. Is there a question that you have which is not answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211534/how-to-interpret-quadratic-terms), with respect to quadratic regression? Because there are many more possible polynomial models than there are CV users, it would seem that the distinction between second- and third-degree polynomials is not as important as understanding how regression with basis expansion works generally.

Comment: Your explicit question is well answered in the linked thread. The problem, I suspect, is not w/ the question you actually asked. You should not be using linear regression w/ a response that is 0 to 9. You need to use ordinal logistic regression (& interpret the polynomial coefficients as in the linked thread), then you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, I did that. I get +- same results. And no, my data is without mistakes or high / low values.
In my view, it has to do with 0 to 1 coding of the variable.